# Issue in sending keys to a website using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

The objective is to sent both username and password key into a Website login page. No link can be provided for privacy reason.

For this, I had tried both the Xpath and CSS selector approach. However, each technique give me a different error.

For example, using the `xpath` approach as below;

```
user_id =self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//[@id='tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_tcl_Username']")
user_id.send_keys( 'username' )

user_pw = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*=[@id='tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_tcl_Password']")
user_pw.send_keys( '12345678' )
```

will output an error;

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Whereas, using `CSS` selector as below;

```
user_id= WebDriverWait( self.browser, 20 ).until(EC.presence_of_element_located( (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_tcl_Username.form-control.input-lg') ) )

user_id.send_keys( 'username' )
```

will output an error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I had play around with different `xpath` & `css` path, but, it does not provide any better result.

The full html/path to each of the username box and password are given below;

#### User Name

```
<div class="form-group m-b-tcl">
 <input name="tcl$MainContentPlaceHolder$tcl$Username" type="text" 
 id="tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_tcl_Username" class="form-control input-lg" 
 placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
 <span id="tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_tcl_UserNameRequired" 
  style="color:#CC0011;visibility:hidden;"></span>
</div>
```

#### Password

```
<div class="form-group m-b-tcl">
 <span id="tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_PasswordRequired" 
 style="visibility:hidden;"></span>  <input name="tcl$MainContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$Password" 
 type="password" id="tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_tcl_Password" 
 class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

I really appreciate if someone can show where did I do wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_elements_by_xpath()` will returns as list.You need to change it `find_element_by_xpath()` which returns as webelement.

```
user_id =self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_tcl_Username']")
user_id.send_keys( 'username' )
```

---

For second one your css selector is wrong.For id you need to add `#` when you are using css selector.

```
user_id= WebDriverWait( self.browser, 20 ).until(EC.presence_of_element_located( (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_tcl_Username.form-control.input-lg') ) )
user_id.send_keys( 'username' )
```

Comment: argh, thanks for point out the diff btw element & elements and #. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

You do get this Error because `find_elements_by_xpath` is returning a list. You should try `find_element_by_xpath`

```
user_id =self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//[@id='tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_tcl_Username']")
```

Besides that, the Xpath is not a legal expression, because you do not specify the Tag you are searching for. Try Following:

```
user_id =self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_tcl_Username']")
user_id.send_keys( 'username' )

user_pw = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='tcl_MainContentPlaceHolder_tcl_Password']")
user_pw.send_keys( '12345678' )
```